# How many days does or do it take?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which one is correct?

> How many days do it take?

or

> How many days does it take?

Answer (score 2):

> How many days do it take?

or

> How many days does it take?

The correct one is the second because the **does** here refers to **it** which is the subject and is singular so you would use **does** for singulars, not **do**.

They, we, you + do
It, he, she + does

Comment: Sphinx, @Michael - Well, I think I was confused by the verb preceding the subject here, which I guess is a characteristic of questions or do normal sentences do that too? Also take this example "How many people have voted? vs "How many people has the Government helped?" In the first case, the verb agrees with "people" while in the second with "Government". Is there a resource you can point to where I can read further? [A link I found that touches briefly on this topic](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_v&page=9UFx9rVePVV8.html)

Comment: We can say “How many people has the Government helped?” if we see the government as one thing or "How many people have the Government helped?" if we see the government as a collection of individuals.

Comment: @Michael Yeah I do understand how collective nouns agree both ways. For my particular case you can even replace "Government" with "President" as I was pointing at the difference in subject-verb order like how the subject preceding in one case and succeeding in other.